# Neighbours, duplicates and aggregation with Cypher & Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Maybe I need to spend more time with the Cypher documentation, but with the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (a)-[:friends|colleagues]-(b)
WHERE 'Boston' IN a.lived_in and 'Boston' IN b.lived_in
WITH a, count(b) as c
RETURN a.name, c
```

Why does b contain duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:friends|colleagues]` means "find all `friend` and `colleague` relationships".

Because a node `a` can be both a friend AND a colleague of another node `b` (or vice versa, since your query is non-directional), the query can find multiple result rows for any given pair of nodes.

When you aggregate (using `COUNT()`) over `a`, any duplicate `b` nodes are included in the aggregation by default.

If you only want to count distinct results for `b`, you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword as follows (I have also simplified the query by removing the unnecessary `WITH` clause):

```
MATCH (a)-[:friends|colleagues]-(b)
WHERE 'Boston' IN a.lived_in AND 'Boston' IN b.lived_in
RETURN a.name, COUNT(DISTINCT b) AS c;
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now. I used the WITH query actually in order to filter out duplicates (in the original query), using WITH collect(distinct b) as b. Any better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to return the *collection* of distinct `b` nodes, then you could use `COLLECT` instead of `COUNT` in my query. Not `WITH` is required.